# [python-click]bash completion not working after upgrade click version from version 7.0 to 8.1.3

Tags: click, bash-completion

Bash completion is working normally with Click 7.0

Environment：

- Python version: 3.9.9
- Click version: 7.0
- Bash version: 5.1.8
- Bash-completion：2.11

This is the code:

```
import click
@click.group(cls=clicommon.AliasedGroup, context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    """SONiC command line - 'show' command"""

    # Load database config files
    load_db_config()
    ctx.obj = Db()

@cli.command()
@click.argument('ipaddress', required=False)
@click.option('-if', '--iface')
@click.option('--verbose', is_flag=True, help="Enable verbose output")
def arp(ipaddress, iface, verbose):
    """Show IP ARP table"""
    cmd = "nbrshow -4"

    if ipaddress is not None:
        cmd += " -ip {}".format(ipaddress)

    if iface is not None:
        if clicommon.get_interface_naming_mode() == "alias":
            if not ((iface.startswith("PortChannel")) or
                    (iface.startswith("eth"))):
                iface = iface_alias_converter.alias_to_name(iface)

        cmd += " -if {}".format(iface)

    run_command(cmd, display_cmd=verbose)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Bash complete config file is like this:

```
root@localhost:~# cat /etc/bash_completion.d/show 
_show_completion() {
    COMPREPLY=( $( env COMP_WORDS="${COMP_WORDS[*]}" \
                   COMP_CWORD=$COMP_CWORD \
                   _SHOW_COMPLETE=complete $1 ) )
    return 0
}

complete -F _show_completion -o default show;
```

After upgrade Click to version 8.1.3, the command is OK but the bash complete not working:

```
root@localhost:~# show 
Usage: show [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  SONiC command line - 'show' command

Options:
  -h, -?, --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  aaa                   Show AAA configuration
  acl                   Show ACL related information
  alarm                 Show alarm info
  arp                   Show IP ARP table
```

```
root@localhost:~# show .
./   .bash_history  .bash_profile  .cshrc   .docker/  .python_history  .viminfo
../  .bash_logout   .bashrc        .curlrc  .lesshst  .tcshrc
```

I have change the configuration of  `/etc/bash_completion.d/show`, but it is not working for me, i want the bash complete working normally.

Comment: `not working` is not quite helpful for  others to understand your problem. what is the expected behavior and whats the real behavior?

Comment: The expected behavior is that after enter show and press TAB can list subcommands.    Like:                                                                                                         
root@localhost:~# show 
arp                                                                                             
After upgrade Click to version 8.1.3， after enter show and press TAB ，can not list the subcommands                                                                              
root@localhost:~# show .
./   .bash_history

Comment: what's `show .` about?

Comment: your script failed to run for me. please post a [repro].

Comment: what's show . about? –  After  upgrade Click to version 8.1.3，When type  " show <TAB>"  can not auto-Complete "arp" , Click 7.0 is OK;  I wonder the bash  complete config file whether is OK with Click to version 8.1.3。

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/f8857cb03268b5b952b88b2acb3e11d9f0f7b6e4/examples/completion/README#L14

```
_SHOW_COMPLETE=source show
# change to
_SHOW_COMPLETE=bash_source show
```

`source` change to `bash_source`